# error: expected primary-expression before ']' token with struct

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

int Height[ Point ];
```

I get this error when I try to declare a new vector with the type "Point" inside. The error is

> error: expected primary-expression before ']' token

on the last line (with int Height....)

Comment: You're declaring an array, it is expecting a constant expression that will give it the size of the array, instead you gave it a typename. What were you trying to do?!?

Comment: I'm trying to assign every point a value "Height"

Comment: What is the type of Height?

Comment: Height is an integer (int)

Comment: Do you want to have points as key in an association or do you want to store points? For the former, research `std::map`, for the latter, you only need to change the typo of the array from `int` to `Point` and then put the number of elements between the square brackets.

Comment: how is a struct of two ints supposed to be assigned a single int?

Comment: You seem confused about how arrays and structures work, I'd recommend you go pick up a good book or tutorial, or you'll keep running into this kind of issues.

Comment: [This may help you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed846cc6f9c1a1a) but as tux3 said, you might want to get a book on C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int Height[ Point ];` means make an array of type `int` named `Height` with a number of elements equal to `Point`.  This is not what you want.  To make any array of `Point` objects you can use `Point height[some_constant_number]`.  If you need to have a dynamic array then use a vector: `std::vector<Point> points;`